# Where can i find mySql Connector 6.3.0 for 64 Bit?

Tags: .net, mysql, connector

we have this old application that we need to port to a new machine but that thing runs using the 6.3.0.0 mySql connector specifically. The mySql site only has 6.3.8 as the closest. tried get an error. so does the latest connector.
(installing this for Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit system)
[image]

Can't find it anywhere. Error i get just for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it in the mySql archives:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=382641

need to register/login

hope this will help someone sometime.

Comment: No need to register, there is a direct "no thanks link" below the login button

Comment: Please extract the actual solution from that remote link and add it here as the answer. This external link may disappear from the internet, may become non-free to register, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting this error as a result of assembly mismatch between the compiled dll and loaded dll. It's not related to your target machine being 64 bit since there is no 64 bit version of Ado.Net connector for MySQL. [All connector binaries are compiled targeting "Any CPU" which should work for both 32 bit and 64 bit machines.](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,519197,525895)

I inspected the dll Sam has provided in his link, and that again targets "Any CPU", not "x64". To inspect you could do

```
System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("MySql.Data.dll").ProcessorArchitecture.ToString();
```

which gives `MSIL` which means "Any CPU".

Or you could do even this:

```
Start/Programs/Microsoft Visual Studio xx/Visual Studio Tools/Command Prompt

cd "directory to dll"

corflags MySql.Data.dll
```

which would give `PE = PE32 and 32BIT = 0` which means its compiled in "Any CPU" platform.